# How to share session between UI and Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, session-state, sql-session-state

I have two applications. One is the User interface, that stores information like UserID on the session. The other is a web api that communicate with the UI. I need to share this UI session with web api.

1- I know that is not recommended to use session with Web Api, but for my purpose I need to do it.

2- I´m using sessionState mode="SQLServer" because of web farm.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=servername;Database=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password;Application Name=name;" cookieless="false" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" timeout="20"/>

<machineKey validationKey="SomeKey" decryptionKey="somekey" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

both applications have the same configuration, but for some reason that i don´t know, it is not doing right.

3 - i´m still developping it locally.

Can someone help me?

Comment: i never tried use sql sessionstate, i used to use session server. that will be more easier.

Comment: in my case I must use sql sessionstate @RayH

Comment: what do you mean by this? "The other is a web api that communicate with the UI". Does UI invokes web API to fetch information?

Comment: @Rex UI invokes web api to save some data into database

Comment: then you may need to use token based authorization. Pass the token in header when wepapi request is invoked and retrieve the session stored in database with in webapi using token. Possibly this only is the only way to share session between 2 apps.

Comment: @Rex Ok, so i need to send this token in the http request header. But what token is it? What do you suggest me to do to send this token?

Comment: Token could be a GUID issued to each user issued for respective successful login. This can be anything that should be unique per user/login(database identity as well). You store this token in cookie or session and as well as database along with session and then pass this token to webapi (either accessing it from cookie or session from UI).